# HTML5 : How do you make different events for different images being dragged then dropped into a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm having a problem where I have 2 Images and I want each when dropped and dragged into a div to play a different video. I.e. Image 1 plays Video 1 , Image 2 plays video 2. The problem is Images 1 and 2 both play the same video. The Image id's are "drag1" and "drag3". Again I would like when "drag1" is dragged and dropped then appended into the div for "video1" to play and when "drag3" is dragged and dropped into the div then appended for another video I haven't inputted yet to play. How do I do this? Right now "drag1" and "drag3" both play "video1". Here's an example of my code.

```
<script>

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.target.removeChild(document.getElementById(data));


    var video = document.getElementById('video1');
     video.style.display = 'block';
     video.play();

    document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        if(!e) { e = window.event; }
        video.style.display = 'none';
    }

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<video id="video1" controls>
  <source src="carrots.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>


<img id="drag2" src="Pot.jpg" draggable="false"
ondragstart="drag(event)" >




<img id="drag1" src="carrots.jpg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" >

<img id="drag3" src="pepper.png" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" >


</body>
</html>
```

and this is the CSS3

```
<style>
body {
    background: url(food-table.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
} 
html 
{ height:100%}

#div1 {width:20%;height:20%;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index:-1;

}
#drag2{width:20%; height:20%; position:absolute;

left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index:-2;

    }
#drag1{ width:10%; height:10%;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:20%;
margin-right: -20%;
transform: translate(-20%, -25%);
z-index:-3;
    }

#drag3{ width:10%; height:10%;
position:absolute;
top:70%;
left:30%;
margin-right: -30%;
transform: translate(-30%, -70%);
z-index:-3;
    }   

#video1{ width:50%; height: 30%;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
display:none;
}
```

Comment: You would need to change the source of the video to match whatever image was dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an id to your source like:

```
<video id="video1" controls>
  <source id="video1-source" src="carrots.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and then change the sources 'src' attribute to the appropriate source.

```
 var video = document.getElementById('video1');
 document.getElementById('video1-source').setAttribute('src', 'youNewSource');
 video.style.display = 'block';
 video.play();
```